# How can i replace duplicates value from multidimentional array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[0] => array([location] => [10.1111111,106.2222222];);

[1] => array([location] => [10.1111111,106.2222222];)

[2] => array([location] => [10.3333333,106.444444444];)

[3] => array([location] => [10.1111111,106.2222222];)

[4] => array([location] => [10.3333333,106.444444444];)
```

I want to keep first array value ( of duplicate values) , and replace all the duplicate value remaining with random number

```
[0] => array([location] => [10.1111111,106.2222222];)

[1] => array([location] => [10.54545422,106.136633434];)

[2] => array([location] => [10.3333333,106.444444444];)

[3] => array([location] => [10.323123232,106.656565654];)

[4] => array([location] => [10.44342266,106.87878787];)
```

my code but it's not seem to work:

```
foreach($dataMap as $items) {

            $temp = array();
            foreach($items as $value) {

                if(!isset($temp[$value])) {
                    $temp[$value] = '[10.888888,106.999999]';
                }
            }
            $items['location'] = $temp;
        }
```

Comment: code, tried any?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove duplicate values from a multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php)

Comment: i want replace not remove

Answer (score -1):

Usually I create a list or set and validate each value to that list, if exist then replace the decimal values and add to the list or set else add the value, by this we achieve unique values.

This is how I do it in python.

```
import random

arr = list()
arr.append([10.1111111, 106.2222222])
arr.append([10.1111111, 106.2222222])
arr.append([10.3333333,106.444444444])
arr.append([10.1111111, 106.2222222])

print(arr)

# Set to check duplicates..
dup = set()
temp_arr = list()

for each_row in range(len(arr)):
    temp_arr.append([])
    for each_col in range(len(arr[each_row])):
        val = arr[each_row][each_col]
        if val in dup:  # found duplicate
            my_int = int(val)
            # new value
            new_val = round(random.uniform(my_int, my_int+1), 7)
            temp_arr[each_row].append(new_val)
            dup.add(new_val)
        else:
            dup.add(val)  # non duplicates.
            temp_arr[each_row].append(val)
print(temp_arr)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Alexander you can find the details in the comments. It's good enough to understand.